# Area of shapes using methods not working

Tags: methods, area

The idea here is to get user input (Basically the name of a shape) and depending on that input, initialize one of the methods. For example, if someone entered Square, I want the squareArea method to get initialized. But that's not working.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Shapes {
    //Scan1 = scanner for integers
    Scanner Scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Method for finding out area of rectangle
void rectangleArea() {
    System.out.println("Enter dimensions");
    System.out.print("Length: ");
    float length = Scan1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Breadth: ");
    float breadth = Scan1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The area of the is: " + length * breadth);
}
   //method for finding out area of square
void squareArea() {
    System.out.println("Enter dimensions");
    System.out.print("Length: ");
    float length = Scan1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The area of the is: " + length * length);
}
```

}

```
public class AreaOfShapes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Scan2 = scanner for strings
    Scanner Scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Shapes Square = new Shapes();
    Shapes Rectangle = new Shapes();
    System.out.println("Which shape would you like to know the area of?");
    String Shape = Scan2.nextLine();
    /*want to compare input (which in this case is Shape) to a string. So for example, if someone types in Square, I want squareArea to get
    activated*/
    if (Shape.equals(Square)) {
        Square.squareArea();
     //not working
    } else if (Shape.equals(Rectangle)) {
        Rectangle.rectangleArea();
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("The shape you've entered does not exist in our database");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about calling methods, not initializing them. I don't really understand which part isn't working but if this (    if (Shape.equals(Square)) {
        Square.squareArea();
     //not working ) is the part that isn't working well, it's because the first Square should be written like this: "Square" (so that it can be a String which you could compare with the scanner input). If something else is not working, please be more specific and I'll try to help a bit more.

Comment: Should end up looking like this:

 if (Shape.equals("Square")) { Square.squareArea();}

Comment: Quotation marks. That's what I was missing. I feel so stupid now. Thanks for helping me out. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Glad to help, it's my first answer ever :) Good luck with your learning!

Comment: Excuse me, could you please accept my answer? It would benefit us both. Thank you.

Comment: I actually have no idea how to do it. But if you could tell me how to, I will.

Comment: As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows. Click the checkmark next to the post that best answers your question to accept that answer as the best one.